# imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation returns nil GPUImagePicture?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I want  to convert image  to **black and white**. i have tried the following code but `imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation` always returns nil.

```
-(UIImage *)convertImageToBlackAndWhite:(UIImage *)image{
GPUImagePicture *gpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter *edgeFilter = [[GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];

GPUImageColorMatrixFilter *conversionFilter = [[GPUImageColorMatrixFilter alloc] init];
conversionFilter.colorMatrix = (GPUMatrix4x4){
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
};

[gpuImage addTarget:edgeFilter];
[edgeFilter addTarget:conversionFilter];
[gpuImage processImage];
NSLog(@"%@",[conversionFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0]);
return [conversionFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0];
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the recent changes in the way that GPUImage handles framebuffers](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/03/17/switching-gpuimage-use-cached-framebuffers), you need to add the line

```
[conversionFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
```

right before

```
[gpuImage processImage];
```

in the above code. You need to let the framework know to not recycle the framebuffer for your last filter until you've processed your image and captured the result from it.

Comment: Thnkas for ur response but now i am getting only the white portion. nothing on that.